# Mantaflow render with transparent background turns out be white screen

Tags: transparency, fire, mantaflow

So I'm rendering an animation with Mantaflow, but when I render it, even in the render result there is good render, but when I'm saving on a disk it turns out to be white screen. Why?
PS: Normal objects renders just fine.
Here's link to a blender file

https://blendswap.com/blend/27948

please help, I have done everything

[image: in render result]

Comment: Are you trying to save it as a JPG? Cause JPG doen't have an alpha channel. You need to export as PNG to use the alpha information.

Comment: No, I was trying to save as a png even as a OpenEXR but output is just white screen.

Comment: Could you add the .blend file using blendswap? There's virtually no information to review here.

Comment: Yes of course. Thank you, for you time.
Here's link
https://blendswap.com/blend/27948

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found another solution for this transparency, It seems like it's some kind of bug or workflow that for me is totally not understandable.
I render it normally as a RGB and in the compositor I'm changing the black pixels to transparent one like this:
[image]